# どこ vs なん which one is better in the sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, nuances, pronouns

> Q: あの立派な建物は何ですか。／あの立派な建物は何処ですか。
> A: あの立派な建物は留学生食堂です。

Which of the question sounds more natural in the given context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only interrogative word 何{なん} works here, because the reply gives information about the function/nature of the building as opposed to where it is.

どこ would work in a context like this:

> 写真で見た立派な建物は何処ですか？
> 食堂の後ろです。

Answer (score 1):

Do you have more context on your question? Additionally, what are your guesses so far?

Note that both questions mean different things: "What is that splendid building / Where is that splendid building?". They are **not** two different ways of asking for the same information. From the provided answer, I'm inclined to believe that the more natural question would be the first one:

> What is that splendid building? That splendid building is the exchange students' canteen.

> Where is that splendid building? That splendid building is [in] the exchange student's canteen.

In the case of the second sentence, you could stretch the point and imagine that the canteen is somehow a smaller part or section of a larger, splendid building you have been discussing previously and therefore you are using あの立派な建物 as a label or identifier rather than as a description.

However, if you swap the terms あの立派な建物 and 留学生の食堂, then the second question with どこですか makes more sense:

> 留学生の食堂はどこですか。あの立派な建物です。Where is the exchange students' canteen ? It's that splendid building.

Note that the structure of the sentence is exactly the same, neither is more correct than the other in terms of syntax. However, **it just makes more or less sense depending on the *meaning* of the words used**.

It's only natural that you ask for *what* something is based on a description (立派な建物), whereas if you have the definition or the concept (留学生の食堂), then it makes no sense to ask for *what* it is, but for other related information, e.g. where it is, what is the time table or whatever.